# Nodejs asynchronous confusion

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I can't seem to grasp how to maintain async control flow with NodeJs. All of the nesting makes the code very hard to read in my opinion. I'm a novice, so I'm probably missing the big picture.

What is wrong with simply coding something like this...

```
function first() {
    var object = {
        aProperty: 'stuff',
        anArray: ['html', 'html'];
    };
    second(object);
}

function second(object) {
    for (var i = 0; i < object.anArray.length; i++) {
        third(object.anArray[i]);
    };
}

function third(html) {
    // Parse html
}
first();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "big picture" is that any I/O is non-blocking and is performed asynchronously in your JavaScript; so if you do any database lookups, read data from a socket (e.g. in an HTTP server), read or write files to the disk, etc., you *have* to use asynchronous code. This is necessary as the event loop is a single thread, and if I/O wasn't non-blocking, your program would pause while performing it.

You *can* structure your code such that there is less nesting; for example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('some_mysql_library');

fs.readFile('/my/file.txt', 'utf8', processFile);

function processFile(err, data) {
  mysql.query("INSERT INTO tbl SET txt = '" + data + "'", doneWithSql);
}

function doneWithSql(err, results) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("There was a problem with your query");
  } else {
    console.log("The query was successful.");
  }
}
```

There are also flow control libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/) (my personal choice) to help avoid lots of nested callbacks.

You may be interested in [this screencast I created on the subject](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously).

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I need to be using async code, I'm just having trouble figuring out if the code I'm writing is async or not.

Comment: In the example above, if I did a database lookup in function `one` and set data to the properties of `object`, would `second` be called only when `object` is fully defined?

Comment: Any function that does async I/O will take a callback which will be called when the I/O is done processing.

Comment: No, but it's also not "waiting" on anything. The only reason for code to be asynchronous is that something needs to happen in the future, and in Node, this happens when you perform I/O and need to know when it's done. It sounds like you're trying to "make" your code async, when in reality using Node.js' async file/socket IO modules will give you this property automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrandonTilley said, I/O is asynchronous, so you *need* callbacks in Node.js to handle them. This is why Node.js can do so much with just a single thread (it's not actually doing more in a single thread, but rather than having the thread wait around for the data, it just starts processing the next task and when the I/O comes back, then it'll jump back to that task with the callback function you gave it).

But, nested callbacks can be taken care of with a good library like the venerable [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or my new little library: [queue-flow](https://github.com/dfellis/queue-flow). They handle the callback issues and let you keep your code un-nested and looking very similar to blocking, synchronous code. :)