# NodeJS iterates too fast with knex

Tags: database, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having some difficulties with a for-loop with queries (knexjs.org) in it. Let's start how I iterate through my array. My array looks like this:

```
[ { module_id: 9, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 9, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 2, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 2, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 4, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 4, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 1, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 1, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 8, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 8, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 7, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 7, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 5, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 5, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 3, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 3, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 6, able: '1', will: '1' },
{ module_id: 6, able: '1', will: '1' } ]
```

Then the "fun" part comes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var object = obj[i];
        console.log("has object", object);
        db.knex('interests').where({
            inventory_id: inventory_id,
            module_id: object.module_id
        }).select().limit(1).then(function (result) {
            console.log("MODULE ID", object.module_id);
            if (result.length == 0) {

                db.knex('interests').insert({
                    inventory_id: inventory_id,
                    module_id: object.module_id,
                    could: object.able,
                    would: object.will
                }).then(function (a) {
                });
            } else {
                db.knex('interests').where({
                    inventory_id: inventory_id,
                    module_id: object.module_id
                }).update({
                    could: object.able,
                    would: object.will
                }).then(function (a) {
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

What the code does is the following:

- Iterate through the array
- Query the database
- If no results, create something
- If results, update something

There is just one problem. The for-loop is **too** fast. Or, in other words: the **query** is too slow. Why? Because *object.module_id* is always the last *module_id* from the array.

How can I make sure it uses the module_id from the for-loop, instead of the variable it was given the last time it has been iterated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, its not that Node is too fast. It's because the queries work **asynchronously**.

The process won't wait for the query to finish to continue the loop. By the time they get executed, the loop has already ended.

I'd suggest <strike>wrapping all your queries/updates in functions with the data as parameters:</strike> chaining your callback methods so they can work as intended

```
 var queryinterest =   function(object){
       db.knex('interests').where({
       inventory_id: inventory_id,
       module_id: object.module_id
    }).select().limit(1).then(function (result) {
        if (result.length == 0) {
                insertInterest(object)
        } else {
                updateInterest(object)             
    })
}
```

Then calling them in the main loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        queryInterests(obj[i])
        });
    }
```

**EDIT:** This post is great for clarifying why and how to work asynchronous:

[Nodejs asynchronous confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594303/nodejs-asynchronous-confusion?rq=1)

Comment: We're almost there, thanks for your help so far... yet, in queryinterest, the 'return q_result' returns undefined because the query hasn't finished then... how to fix that?

Comment: whoops I think I made a typo `q_restult` instead of `q_result`, I edited my code!

Comment: That doesn't work either. The return `q_result` is reached before `q_result = result`

Answer (score 0):

I put together this method for a similar scenario, that you might find useful.
Say you need to grab and parse the next invoice number from a stack or you need to grab a users full name, before you can insert or update a record.
Rather than coding a specific call for each select its obviously gonna be better if you have a generic function:

```
async function select(table, args, single){
    //assumes you've already configured your knex object database details(hostname, password etc)
    return await knex.select().from(table).where(args).then(function(result) {
            //this formats the result into an easier to parse structure
            let returnObject = {};
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {

                returnObject[key] = value
            }
            //this will toggle whether you want all the rows returned or just the first, handy if you know theres only one match, but not strictly needed for this
            if (single == true) {
                return (returnObject[0])
            } else {
                return (returnObject);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then in your main loop:

```
(async function(){
        const result = await select('tableName',args,true);                        
        console.log(result);
})()
```

Voila! You've got your data ready for additional formatting before being used in your update/insert. Where you see the console.log is usually where I do any string operations, loops etc, just to keep it a bit more obviously segmented in the code.